# Can we call Office 365 API from Linux machine?

Tags: linux, api, office365

We've developed our own cloud-based email solution on top of Linux. We're providing Admin Interface to clients where they can create, modify, delete users/groups. Few of our clients are using Office 365 service for few mailboxes. We would like to make an API call to office 365 whenever there is any activity performed (Create, modify, delete user, etc.) by clients on our admin panel for office 365 users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to interact with user accounts and mailboxes, you should be able to do most of what you want with Microsoft Graph via REST calls:

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user

Also see the Office 365 API reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/rest-api-overview#sectionLanguagesIDEs